# How do I make square cropped images responsive with overlay responsive

Tags: html, css

This is all in my React App. I have multiple images with different ratios that I am cropping into squares. When you scroll over the squares an overlay comes up. I then want those square images to be responsive when the page gets small.

Here is an example of what I have now. Ignore the silly images, just put in images with diff pixel sizes. I know I have the image and container sizes set but I want the images to be square and responsive.

When the screen is wide:
[image: Full screen]

As screen compresses:
[image: When the screen starts compresing]

Relevant code -

Postindex.js

```
<Grid.Column key = {post.id} mobile={16} tablet={8} computer={4}>
<Link to={'/post/'+ (post.slug) }>
  <div className = "imgContainer">
    <img className = "thumbImage" src = {post.image}/>
    <div className = "overlay">
      <h6 className ="text">{post.title}</h6>
      </div>
  </div>
</Link>
</Grid.Column>
```

App.css

```
.imgContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 225px;
  width: 225px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.thumbImage {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 225px;
  width: 225px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Your images should be wrapping to a new line, since they have a fixed pixel size of 225px and aren't inherently responsive. What's keeping them all on the same row?

Comment: @JonUleis I was trying to use the Semantic UI React Grid system which is what is keeping them on the same line. I can remove that though if neccessary

Comment: I see. Try replacing the first three lines of your `.thumbImage` styles with `display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%` to see where that gets you. It's possible the grid framework will resize the `.imgContainer` elements despite the hardcoded sizes in your CSS, but it definitely won't automatically resize the hardcoded values in the `<img>` inside them, so removing that CSS could help.

Comment: @JonUleis Yeah, I made those changes and they didn't help. So when I change the height and width to 100% in .imgContainer, the images are responsive, but they aren't square. If I change back to set a pixel size to make the images square, then they aren't responsive. It just seems like I can't have both at the same time.

Comment: Does `.imgContainer` stay a square regardless of the `<img class="thumbImage">` inside? If so, you could set `.thumbImage` to `position: absolute; top; 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;` so it fills the square container and stays cropped with the `object` properties.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. Tried it and the images get all glitchy.